# laravel update row to be a copy of another already existing row

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to copy all data from one row to another already existing row and change some values.
For example

1. if the user wants to update row#1, all updates are saved in addition it creates a new row with the current date and new id like row#2.
   `$updatedEmp = $emp->replicate();`
2. if the user wants to update the same row#1 again, all changes are saved but this time row#2 does already exist. I want to copy all changes from row#1 to row#2 but with the same id of row#2. I've tried to use replicate() function, but it creates a new row and I get an error duplicate for primary key.

I've tried to change the id, but it did not work

```
if($query){ //not empty
 $updatedEmp = $emp->replicate();
 $updatedEmp->id = $query->id;
 $query = $updatedEmp;
 $query->save();
}
```

I don't have problems with step 1 but step 2 is not working for me. How can I make laravel to update the row instead of inserting a new one?